# Where is System.Diagnostics.Debug.Listeners property in netstandard 2?

Tags: .net-standard-2.0

The ms doc says it should exist a Listeners property in Debug.Diagnostics.Debug in netstandard 2, but this is not the case in a real project. The Listeners property is undefined.

I tryed adding the System.Diagnostics.Debug nuget with no luck.

Any clue?

Comment: .NETCore does not have this property, that makes it non-standard.  As you can tell from [this github page](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/31003), this is a pretty big obstacle to porting programs and they recently worked on getting this fixed.  Whether that means it gets added to a new .netstandard remains to be seen.  Do keep in mind that a library ought not mess with listeners, configuring them is a task that belongs to the main app.  Always a good idea to mention why you need it so users can propose an alternative.

Answer (score 3):

When you try to navigate to the page for [Debug.Listeners Property for .NET Standard 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug.listeners?view=netframework-4.7.2&viewFallbackFrom=netstandard-2.0) the page clearly states:

> The requested page is not available for .NET Standard 2.0. You have been redirected to the newest product version this page is available for.

Diving in a bit deeper, you can find all APIs implemented in .NET standard 2 on [their github](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/standard/master/docs/versions/netstandard2.0_ref.md). Here you can see that the `public static class Debug` doesn't have a `Listeners` property.

However, the article on the Debug.Listeners Property I referred to above also states

> The Listeners collection is shared by both the Debug and the Trace classes; adding a trace listener to either class adds the listener to both.

The .NET standard API's also learns us that the `public sealed class Trace` *does* implement `public static TraceListenerCollection Listeners { get; }`. This would lead me to believe you can access the Listeners through the [`Trace class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.trace.listeners?view=netstandard-2.0).